# How to answer a question that was migrated away, then closed and migrated back?

Tags: support, closed-questions, migration

In this question: [my php script does not work](https://superuser.com/questions/1513282/my-php-script-does-not-work), the answer was migrated away correctly to Stack Overflow.

Stack Overflow closed the question being unclear as I was adding my answer and that action migrated it back to SuperUser.

How can I post my answer now? To me it is clear as day what the question is and the answer is relatively simple too, but I have too little reputation on Stack Overflow to do anything. I did flag the question, but given that it was migrated back to SuperUser, I doubt they can do anything with the question now.

How does this work?

Comment: Just ask it again on [so] and make sure it is clear. Have your self answer ready to immediately post.

Comment: It was not my question. I don't feel like asking the question and answering it if it is someone else's question though...

Comment: @DavidPostill I decided to do what you suggested anyway, posted a new question and checked answer my own question to provide that answer.

Comment: Question was sent back to us due to the original author’s request for suggestions on their code (more than likely) and the vague description (it does not work).  It definitely isn’t within scope at Super User only potentially at Stack Overflow

Comment: I agree. Normally migration should only be executed when a question will fit perfectly on the target site and not when it is likely to be closed there anyway. In this instance, the question should have been closed at SuperUser with a comment below that such questions should be posted on StackOverflow, but that they need to reword the question because it would otherwise be closed there too.